# How to best design In-Apps for iPhone Book Store like app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, in-app-billing

I am designing an iPhone application like iBooks. The user will see a shelf of books and we intend to sell the content (books) in two ways

1 - Buy Individual Book

2 - Subscription

So what would be the best way to design in-apps around these scenarios? I mean we've to keep in-app-restoration in mind too.

I was thinking to multiple in-app 'LEVELS' like $0.99, $1.99 and so on. And consume appropriate purchase relative to price of an individual book. But then how would users be able to restore ?

I have an external server where I can keep track of which user purchased which book ? Does it help in any way ?

Or would I have to use a separate in-app entry for every single book in the application ? And add a new in-app in iTunesConnect every time I add a new book available to users ?

Thanks for reading and I look forward to your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion you need to go with individual In App with Non-Consumable Category.

- You need to register the required In-App purchase, Its not necessary to register individual InApp purchase for each book.
- You can assign the same In App identifier to multiple books, but at the same time you need to make book id should be different for all books.
- Now at the server end you need to keep track of userid, bookid & is purchased flag.
- Now let say user have purchased one book so you will update the is purchase flag on server for that user only.
- Now if user have deleted the application & re-installing it again at that time we can get updated data from the server for that user & display unlocked books.
- Need to do same for all user.

Hope it helps you, Let me know if you need anymore clarification for this.